# Space items in inline list

Tags: html, css

How do I create enough space between the items in the following list so that users of mobile devices don't click on the wrong link. Note that the list is horizontal. Note also that the list can wrap so the issue is both in the vertical and horizontal planes.

```
ul#menu li {
  display:inline;
}

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="/list/A">Ant</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/B">Bear</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/C">Cat</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/D">Dog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/E">Elf</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/F">Fish</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/G">Gorilla</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/H">Hourse</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/I">Indigo</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/J">Japan</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/K">Knight</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/L">Laos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/M">Mouse</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/N">Nigeria</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/O">Orange</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/P">Pony</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/Q">Queen</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/R">Rat</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/S">Stoat</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/T">Tiger</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/U">Uganda</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/V">Vermont</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/W">Wales</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/X">Xray</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/Y">York</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/Z">Zambia</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` layout model, and then `margin-right`, `margin-bottom`.

```css
ul#menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul#menu li {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="/list/A">Ant</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/B">Bear</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/C">Cat</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/D">Dog</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/E">Elf</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/F">Fish</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/G">Gorilla</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/H">Hourse</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/I">Indigo</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/J">Japan</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/K">Knight</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/L">Laos</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/M">Mouse</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/N">Nigeria</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/O">Orange</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/P">Pony</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/Q">Queen</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/R">Rat</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/S">Stoat</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/T">Tiger</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/U">Uganda</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/V">Vermont</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/W">Wales</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/X">Xray</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/Y">York</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/Z">Zambia</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `margin: 5px` or `line-height: 200%`. First moves it horizontally, next vertically.

Comment: This will create unnecessary padding above the first line.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

ul#menu li {
  margin: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="/list/A">Ant</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/B">Bear</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/C">Cat</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/D">Dog</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/E">Elf</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/F">Fish</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/G">Gorilla</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/H">Hourse</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/I">Indigo</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/J">Japan</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/K">Knight</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/L">Laos</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/M">Mouse</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/N">Nigeria</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/O">Orange</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/P">Pony</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/Q">Queen</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/R">Rat</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/S">Stoat</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/T">Tiger</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/U">Uganda</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/V">Vermont</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/W">Wales</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/X">Xray</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/Y">York</a></li>
  <li><a href="/list/Z">Zambia</a></li>
</ul>
```